# Paper status "Accept with Shepherd". What does it really mean?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, workshop

Recently, one of my works have received the status of **Accept with Shepherd**. We have received many suggestions from the reviewers.

I'd like to know in more detail in which real status is my paper and if it has been accepted or it is in a sort of minor/major review.

The paper is for a workshop of a CS conference.

Comment: Possibly this? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109827/duties-of-a-shepherd-in-a-cs-conference . I have to say I find this terminology a tad paternalistic...

Comment: Is this a PLoP conference? Such as EuroPLoP?

Comment: It means you need to include your priest as a coauthor.  :-P

Comment: They believe it would be of benefit for other people to know about your work,  but they are not happy with the quality of the **presentation** of your work.

Comment: @Sean hopefully it was anonymous!

Comment: @Buffy no, it is not.

Comment: Ok. I have less to say, then. The meaning of shepherding is clear in the Patterns community and I don't know how it translates to other areas. Shepherding is very intense and iterative in our community. It is also very helpful.

Comment: @darijgrinberg How on earth is it "paternalistic"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm talking about the word choice, not about the actual procedure it stands for, which I hope is a more co-operative form of refereeing (a good and overdue thing). I take it you are aware of the connotations of the word "sheep" in European languages :) Anyway, that comment of mine is not be taken too seriously.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I have no idea what you're talking about. Sheep have nothing to do with "patriarchy". This is a bad time in the history of this community for such jokes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "paternalistic" has to do with [paternalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternalism), not with patriarchy, though the two are hardly completely unrelated. And why, I think it is a great time to remind people that paternalism is generally not welcomed ;)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Oh, right :D

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Your paper will be shepherded.** The conference organizers will assign a contact person called *shepherd* to your paper, who guides you through a sequence of revisions (for further information, see the [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109827/duties-of-a-shepherd-in-a-cs-conference) mentioned by @darijgrinberg, and [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/thanking-a-shepherd-in-acknowledgments)).

The "accept with..." decision signals you that they really want your paper at the workshop, stronger than in the case of a major revision. But similar to a minor revision, there's still a possibility that your paper will be rejected, if you don't work cooperatively with the shepherd.

Comment: Let me reinforce the “they want your paper” part. In my experience (HCI conferences), shepherding happens when the manuscript is viewed as having a strong contribution, but solvable peripheral issues (usually presentation-related) mean it’s not publishable as-is. In my field, being a shepherded paper is *good* because you’ll get relatively senior guidance developing your ideas better.

Answer (score 13):

In my experience as a conference program chair, shepherding is usually applied to borderline papers, where the chairs think the paper has valuable material but flaws too serious for publication in its current form.

Assigning a shepherd for the paper means that your acceptance is conditional on revising to address those flaws. It's still good news, however, in that the conference wouldn't be assigning you a shepherd unless they think that you *can* overcome the current flaws and produce an acceptable paper.  Moreover, it is normally the case that you are invited to communicate back and forth with a shepherd to make sure that your revisions are on target---the conference wants you to succeed in your revision.

What you need to do now is to communicate with the shepherd about your revision plan and make sure that what you want to do matches what they will consider acceptable. If you can find agreement on a set of acceptable revisions and successfully execute them, then your paper should become finally accepted.